# Svelte with Apollo GraphQl - Mutation is not getting triggered

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, svelte

I'm working with my own `api` and I can see it work if I use `@urql/svelte` but since we're using `Apollo` with `React` on most of our projects, I would like to see the differences between frameworks using the same dependency.

My `lib/client.js` looks like this:

```js
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core';

function createApolloClient() {
    const httpLink = new HttpLink({
        uri: 'MY_API'
    });

    const cache = new InMemoryCache();

    const client = new ApolloClient({
        httpLink,
        cache
    });

    return client;
}

const client = new createApolloClient();

export default client;
```

My `index.svelte` is looking like this

```html
<script>
    import { setClient, mutation } from 'svelte-apollo';
    import { gql } from '@apollo/client/core';
    import { browser } from '$app/env';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    import client from '../lib/client';

    const email = 'AN_EMAIL';
    const password = 'A_PASSWORD';

    let userName;
    let isLoggedIn = false;

    setClient(client);

    const SIGN_IN = gql`
        mutation ($email: String!, $password: String!) {
            userSignIn(email: $email, password: $password) {
                email
                id
                isEnabled
                name
                surname
                userType
            }
        }
    `;

    const signInMutation = mutation(SIGN_IN);

    async function signInAction() {
        await try {
            signInMutation({ variables: { email, password } }).then((result) => console.log(result));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    const isUserLoggedIn = () => {
        if (browser && localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') && localStorage.getItem('userName')) {
            isLoggedIn = true;
            userName = localStorage.getItem('userName');
        }
    };

    onMount(() => {
        isUserLoggedIn();
    });
</script>

<button on:click={signInAction}>Trigger</button>

{#if isLoggedIn}
    <h1>Welcome {userName}</h1>
{/if}
```

I honestly can't figure out what I'm missing with the Apollo setup.
I have no errors on my console and my network doesn't show anything when I click the button. The UI seems to work fine with the `urql` setup.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Is the `await` keyword before `try` a typo? You don't need it there. And since you're using the `signInMutation().then()` form, you don't need it at all, nor do you need to make `signInAction` async.

Comment: I've followed Hasura's tutorial and that's where the `await` comes from. Honestly, I wasn't sure what it was doing either: https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/svelte-apollo/mutations-variables/3-create-mutation/

Comment: That being said, even without the `await` I'm not able to do the mutation. My `network` is still showing blank and I'm not entirely sure on what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your `client` setup:

```js
// ...
// const client = new createApolloClient(); // wrong use of 'new' keyword, createApolloClient() is a regular function, not a class constructor!
const client = createApolloClient(); 
// ...
```

As stated in my comment, you also have an issue in your `signInAction` function definition. You need to settle for *one* syntax:

```js
// async/await
async function signInAction() {
    try {
        const result = await signInMutation({ variables: { email, password } });
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

// then/catch
function signInAction() {
    signInMutation({ variables: { email, password } })
        .then((result) => console.log(result))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Off-topic and opinionated: `svelte-apollo` radically differs from the react apollo client, is not an 'official' apollo client, and has not been updated for the past year+. You will be much better off going back to `@urql/svelte`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Even with your suggestion my mutation is still not getting triggered but I have no `logs` on what might be happening and all I'm doing is the code that I have above (adding your changes to it, of course).
I was trying to use `apollo` and `svelte-apollo` mostly because I already know its logic from `react` and was trying to reuse that. I also couldn't figure out how to trigger `queries` with `@urql` only when I want to but I guess that probably has to do with my knowledge with `Svelte` and not `urql`, I would say

Comment: @ItzaMi I'm at a loss in how I can further help you. The rest of your code looks fine. Perhaps double-check your Apollo client configuration (URI), and make sure you can run a very basic query (one that requires no variables and returns a simple scalar-typed response like "Hello world") off of the same configuration, then incrementally build up on that foundation. As for `@urql`, from my own experience, the initial client configuration is slightly more complex, but running queries/mutations/subs past that initial hurdle is very straightforward. Good luck!